# Why absolute continuous function has bounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ absolute continuous, i.e. there is $g\in L^1(a,b)$ s.t. $$f(x)-f(y)=\int_x^y g.$$

Why such function has bounded variation on $[a,b]$ ?

In my solution they say that it's a consequence of the fact that $$\forall \varepsilon >0, \exists \delta >0: \forall E\text{ measurable s.t. }m(E)<\delta \implies \int_E f<\varepsilon .\tag{(*)}$$

But I don't really understand in what is useful. Don't we have the following fact : Let $\pi: a=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=b$ a subdivision.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|f(t_{i+1})-f(t_i)|\leq \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\int_{t_{i}}^{t_{i+1}}|g|=\int_a^b |g|,$$

Therefore, $$\sup_{\{a=t_0<...<t_n=b\} \in \Pi(a,b)}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}|f(t_{i+1})-f(t_i)|\leq \int_a^b|g|<\infty ,$$

and thus has bounded variation. Isn't it correct ? If yes, in what $(*)$ is relevant ?

Comment: Maybe because they were expecting a proof starting from [this form of the definition of absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Definition).

Comment: If so, how do you connect absolute continuity and $(*)$ in my question ? @conditionalMethod

Comment: Herman: You proof is correct, but I agree with @conditionalMethod that they probably wanted you to use the definition that he is mentioning. You should think a bit yourself about how you can connect this to the property ($\ast$) in question. Hint: What does the condition $\sum_k (y_k - x_k) < \delta$ tell you?